# UIActivityIndicator with a complexity

Tags: iphone

I want to show a UIActivityIndicator with text in a square box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `addSubview` on your `UIActivityIndicatorView` instance and pass in a framed `UILabel`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `UIAlertView` which has title by adding the `UIActivityIndicatorView` as subview to it. then show/dismiss the `UIAlertView` when needed.